# Troubles conceptualizing a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `'Course'` table and an `'Event'` table.
I would like to have all the courses that actually take place, i.e. they are not cancelled by an event.

I have done this by a simple request for all the course and a script analysis (basically some loops), but this request take a time that I believe too long. I think what I want is possible in one query and no loops to optimize this request.

Here are the details :

- `'Course' c` have the fields `'date'`, `'duration'` and a many to many relation with the `'Grade'` table
- `'Event' e` have the fields `'begin'`, `'end'`, `'break'` and a many to many relation with the `'Grade'` table
- A course is cancelled by an event if they occur at the same time and if the event is a break (`e.break = 1`)
- A course is cancelled by an event if all the grades of the course are in the events that occurs at the same time (many events can occurs, I have to sum up the grades of these events and compare them to the grades of the courses). This is the part I'm doing with a loop, I have some trouble to conceptualize that.

Any help is welcome,

Thanks in advance,

PS : I'm using mysql

EDIT : Tables details

-Course

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duration  | time        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type      | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-------+---------------------+----------+------+
| id    | date                | duration | type |
+-------+---------------------+----------+------+
|   1   | 2013-12-10 10:00:00 | 02:00:00 |    0 |
|   2   | 2013-12-11 10:00:00 | 02:00:00 |    0 |
+-------+---------------------+----------+------+
```

-Event

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| begin       | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| end         | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| break       | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | begin               | end                 | break |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2013-12-10 00:00:00 | 2013-12-11 23:59:00 |     1 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

-course_grade

```
+-----------+----------+
| course_id | grade_id |
+-----------+----------+
|     1     |       66 |
|     2     |       65 |
|     2     |       66 |
+-----------+----------+
```

-event_grade

```
+----------+----------+
| grade_id | event_id |
+----------+----------+
|       66 |        1 |
+----------+----------+
```

So here, only the course 2 should appear, because course 1 has only one grade, and this grade has an event.

Comment: Can you post a SQLFiddle please? I'm trying to visualize your schema and failing...

Comment: please put tables samples.bye

Comment: SQL Fiddle IS an option, but also showing sample data even here posting, just dont use tabs for formatting and highlight and Ctrl+K to format text (or with the curly bracket image).  It sounds like school courses with grades, but the event having grades doesn't make sense unless the ex: 1 course has many events (test, mid-term, final exam), and of all the events and grades are break... I would expect STUDENT/GRADEs table if this was the case.

Comment: your 'c' has only a date/duration and no start time? so duration is needless (or is there an implicite starttime?)

Comment: Is it a combination that cancels the course? That is, is a course cancelled if (e.break = 1) *and* the complex thingy about events?

Comment: What kind of field is duration?  An integer (in seconds/minutes/hours/days)?

Comment: I have edited. I didn't know SQL Fiddle, this is interesting, thanks.In fact, the 'date' is the start time, end time is computed with duration. Yes this is a combination. Duration is a time (H:i:s)

Answer (score 0):

1. I like riddles, this is a nice one, has many solutions, I think
2. As you say 'Any help is welcome', I give an answer *altough* its not the solution (and it does not fit into a comment)
3. I dont know, if you just want (A) the naked statement (over and out), or if you want (B) to understand how to get to the solution, I take (B)

I start with 'what would I change' before starting about the solution:

you are mixing `date`,`datetime`,`start`,`end` and `duration`, try to use only one logic (if it is your model ofcourse) ie.

an event/course has a start and an end time (or start/duration)

duration should (IMHO) not be a time

try to find a smallest timeslice for events/course (are there 1 sec events? or is a granularity of 5' (ie. 10:00, 10:05, 10:10 ans so on) a valid compromise?

My solution, a prgmatic one not academic 
(sounds funny, but does work good in a simillar prob I had see annotation)

Create a table (T_TIME_OF_DAY) having all from 00:00, 00:05, .. 23:55

Create a Table (T_DAYS) in a valid and usefull range (a year?)

the carthesian product - call it points in time - (ie. `select date, time from T_DAYS,T_TIME_OF_DAY` no condition) of them (days x times) 300*24*12 ~ 100.000 rows if you need to look at a whole year (and 5' are ok for you) - thats not much and no prob

the next step is to join the curses fitting to your points in time (and the rows are down to <<100.000)

if you next join these with your events (again using point in time) you should get what you want.

```
    simplyfied quarters of a day:

                12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  
                08  09  10  11  12  13  14  15  
                |...|...|...|...|...|...|...|...
    grade 65 (C).............2..................
    grade 66 (C).........1...2..................
    grade 65 (E)................................
    grade 66 (e)........1111..................
```

(annotation: I use this logic to calculate the availabillity of services regarding to their downtimes per Month / Year, and could use the already in timeslices prepared data for display)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. All answers are good to read ;) For the time/datetime, after severals attempts, it is the more convenient for me to have duration as a time. I only have to fetch a week, or a month, not a whole year. In fact you are showing a way to find intersections between courses and events right ? My issue is more about finding the common grades between a course and an event to see  if it is cancelled or not. But thanks for the method, I have never seen this way and I will take the time to analyse it. That sounds interesting.

Comment: you need the intersections between this two tables to find the grades, arent you?

Comment: Yes sure, but I'm currently using something like `(ADDTIME(c.date, c.duration) <= e.begin OR c.date >= e.end) OR conditions...` and it works well. Where I'm really stucked is for the commons grades.

Comment: i gtg to day, sry i'll try to finish te pikture tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

(second answer, because it is a totaly different and mor3 standard aproach)

I made an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ccbf/11) for you

so what to do:

and thats the a solution:

step one (in mind) select course,grades (lets call them C)

step two (in mind) select events, grades (lets call them E)

and - tada -

select all from C where there a no rows in E that have the same grade and the same date(somehow) and eventtype='break'

so your solution:

```
    select 
    id, date start_time, date+duration end_time, grade_id 
    from Course c join course_grade cg on c.id=cg.course_id 
    where not exists ( 
    select grade_id, begin start_time, end end_time 
    from event_grade eg join event e on eg.event_id=e.id
    where 
      eg.grade_id=cg.grade_id
      and e.break=1
      and
       (
       (e.begin<=c.date and e.end >=c.date+c.duration)
       or e.begin between c.date and c.date+c.duration
       or e.end between c.date and c.date+c.duration
       )    

    )
```

*I did take no attention to optimize here*